# Error while parsing JSON response using jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have a sample json response as shown below which i am trying to parse using jq in shell script.`[{"id":1,"notes":"Demo1\nDemo2"}]`

I am first storing the entire json response in a shell variable value.

```
value=$(curl $URL )
```

I am getting an error when trying to access individual variables

```
idval=$(echo $value | jq -r '.[].id'))
```

Can anyone please help resolve the error?

Comment: What's the error? Without knowing that it's a bit hard, but some things to try, if you haven't already:
1) there's a syntax error in your last line, there's an extra bracket at the end. 
2) echo $value to check that curl fetched the JSON correctly
3) consider quoting your variables, eg. "$value" instead of $value
4) does it work if you run it as a one-liner? eg. running `curl "$URL" | jq -r '.[].id'` directly?

Comment: The extra bracket was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote `$value`:

```
echo "$value" | jq -r '.[].id' 
1
```